# Clock disappeared from notification area

Tags: 11.04, gnome-panel

The clock in the notification area disappeared after I removed Ubuntuone from my system and I cant figure out how to get it back.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

make sure you have all of the components of the ubuntu desktop installed. One easy way to do this is to run this in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

That will likely add back in ubuntuone-client, but then you can just remove ubuntuone-client with

```
sudo apt-get remove ubuntuone-client
```

I'd also recommend logging out and back in again to make sure all components are running.

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem and fixed by installing `indicator-datetime`